# Cannot find symbol class @load

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

When I try to compile my Android project, I see the error "cannot find symbol class @load":

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think that there should be an `@load` annotation there in the first place?

Comment: Try posting your actual code so others can reproduce the error. A screenshot of your editor doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean to use the `@Override` annotation rather than the `@load` annotation.